# What is the best/most correct way to prepare the HDD for a dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I need to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04, but first I’d like to know whether or not there is a best / most correct way to do it, technically speaking.

Note 1: Ubuntu will be my default operating system. I'll use Windows only when I have work to do at home.

Note 2: I do not want to use Windows on a virtual machine. Believe me, I've already tried it, but I work with AutoCAD and it gets really slow on a VM. My PC has 4 GB RAM only and I can't afford to buy more RAM for the time being; and -- No! -- I'm not planning on using any program other than AutoCAD, so I'll stick with dual boot for now. No problem.

I have a 1 TB hard drive. My plan is to partition it like this:

900 GB for Ubuntu - 890 GB root (/) and 10 GB swap (for hibernation matters)

100 GB for Windows - which will be more than enough for me

By the way, I don't like using a /home partition.

My doubts are:

1) How should I partition the HDD? 890/10/100 GB? 100/890/10 GB? 890/100/10 GB? I mean, is it better to have the Linux partition at the beginning of the HDD, or should it be the Windows one? Should the swap partition be at the end? Or whatever? Is there a better / more appropriate way to do it?

2) Which should I install first, Windows or Ubuntu? In my experience, it's easier when Ubuntu is installed after Windows. Ubuntu seems to deal very well with GRUB stuff by itself, automatically. But if you guys tell me it's better to install Windows after Ubuntu, I'll definitely do it; just tell me the reasons why and point me to a good guide and I'll follow it.

I want my operating systems to run as smoothly as possible together, so if you can help me with the best technical solution to make it all work correctly, I'll appreciate it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hey, guys. What's up? I understand that the question may lead to an opinion based discussion, but I didn't really asked for opinions. I asked for "the best/most correct way to prepare the HDD for a dual boot" and I'm pretty sure there must be a technical response for that. JonasCz, for instance, gave us a very technical explanation regarding HDD behavior. If he is right or not, I really cannot tell, but he's made his point and it totally makes sense. I believe he was more technical than subjective and that was the kind of answer I was looking for. What do you think? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: There is no "best" way of doing that. That's why it is opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

- Install windows first. During the installation, you will be given the opportunity to tell the installer how to partition your disk. I'd suggest formatting the disk here, and deleting all existing partitions so that there's noting left over from previous use. Then, reate a new 100GB partition for Windows, leaving the rest as unallocated space, and complete the installation.
- Then, Install Ubuntu. I'd choose the option to partition the Disk manually when the installer asks how to install (Side-by-side with windows, replace Windows, or manual). Then, In the unallocated space, create your new 10 GB swap partition, making sure you select to use it as "Linux swap". Next, create your main 890GB main partition for Ubuntu with the rest of the unallocated, and choose "`/`" as the mount point. Note that your 1TB hard drive won't actually give you 1TB - it will show as having a little less space then that.

Ubuntu will take care of setting up GRUB and the dual boot during the installation, and, when your reboot, it  will offer you a menu asking you which OS you want to start - with Ubuntu selected by default, and it starts Ubuntu if you don't choose Windows within 10 sec or so - so you've basically got Ubuntu as your main OS.

Regarding the layout of the partitions of the disk - the beginning of the disk is always faster. This means that the things you use often should be near the beginning of the disk in order to get maximum performance. In this case, the Ubuntu install is fairly close the the beginning of the disk (110GB in), giving you good performance in both Ubuntu and Windows, as well as for the swap partition. Note that the performance differences between the beginning and end of the disk are fairly minor though. This does not apply to SSDs.

You should definitely install Windows first - it's a lot easier.

Comment: JonasCz, so your suggestion is a 100/10/890 GB partition layout, right? I confess I had never thought of placing the swap partition before the root one. That's interesting. And I get your point regarding the beginning of the disk and the operating system performance. Thank you very much for your reply. :)

Comment: @user48949, Yes, Exactly. It's also the easiest way, since AFAIK there's no way to tell the Windows installer to place a new partition at the end of the disk. Regarding swap - putting it at the beginning is good for performance, since it's both at the beginning of the disk (faster), _and_ having it at the beginning of the disk, and not at the very end, avoids seeking across the entire disk when accessing the swap partition, which is also good for performance, especially when it's actually used as swap. If you only use it for hibernation, it doesn't matter much though.

Answer (score 1):

The way I 'd do it is install windows from scratch on the PC formatting the whole HDD. Then I would use the windows disk management utility to shrink the windows partition to 100 Gb. (The last stems from the rule of a thumb: Use windows programs for Windows stuff and linux programs for linux stuff.) Leave the 900 gb as unallocated space. After that I would install Ubuntu. Install Ubuntu alongside windows will handle everything like a charm. The only 'problem' is that this way it will probably not create the 10 gb swap you want, so you may have to manually do it.

Comment: This is not really necessary - you can tell the Windows installer the size of the partition to create during the installation, no need to resize later. I believe it's not even possible to shrink a partition while running windows from it.

Comment: It is, That's how I ve dual booted my laptop. The reason I suggested a full format is so that the HDD is totally cleaned of any previous installation files and the windows bootloader manages to install appropriately (before grub2 succeeds it after installing Ubuntu).

Comment: Yup, I've already done that once, Karsus, on my wife's laptop. Thanks for your reply. :)